# C Seg fault on char ** reading or fclose

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In my code I'm trying to read a file, read it's lines and get them into a String array, then print them and close the file. When I run it, it fails on a seg fault and skips the last line of the file, and I just can't find the problem...
My instinct is to blame reading the array wrongly or misbehaving with the file... Am I right?
Any help or redirects would be helpful.
Thank you!

Here is the main file:

```
#include "files_utils.h"

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("expl", "r");
    if (!fp)
        return -1;
    long lines_count = countlines(fp);
    long flen = file_length(fp);
    String *lines = calloc(lines_count, sizeof(String));
    printf("file length: %ld\n", flen);
    printf("file lines: %ld\n", lines_count);
    getlines(lines, lines_count, fp);
    printf("finished\n");
    for (String *sp = lines; sp != NULL; sp++)
        printf("%s", *sp);
    printf("before close\n");
    fclose(fp);
    printf("closed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the files_utils file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLINE 10

typedef char *String;

long file_length(FILE *fp)
{
    /*
    find the length of the file fp points to, regardless of the current position.
    */
    long original_pos = ftell(fp), i = 0;
    rewind(fp);
    // count chars:
    for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
        i++;
    // return the file to it's original position
    fseek(fp, original_pos, SEEK_SET);
    return i;
}

long countlines(FILE *fp)
{
    /*
    find the amount of lines in file fp points to, regardless of the current position.
    */
    long original_pos = ftell(fp), i = 0;
    rewind(fp);
    // find newlines:
    for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
        if (c == '\n')
            i++;
    // return the file to it's original position
    fseek(fp, original_pos, SEEK_SET);
    return i;
}

String *getlines(String lines[], long maxlines, FILE *fp)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxlines; i++)
    {
        lines[i] = calloc(MAXLINE, sizeof(char));
        fgets(lines[i], MAXLINE, fp);
    }
    return lines;
}
```

And it outputs

```
file length: 144
file lines: 21
finished
... all the lines of the file except of the last one ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Should this `for (int i = 0; i <= maxlines; i++)` be this `for (int i = 0; i < maxlines; i++)`?

Comment: Reading a file to check its size is an anti-pattern.  For that matter, checking the size in any way (except for a utility whose purpose is to report the file size) is pretty much an anti-pattern.  You ought to read the file until EOF, growing the data structure as needed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I don't necessarily agree with the second half of that. In particular, growing a data structure can be significantly less efficient than building it the right size at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was fixed when I changed the printing loop to run until maxlines instead of waiting for NULL. Why is this? Why would waiting for NULL raise a seg fault?

Comment: You can't ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) in an answer.